# Zip Code Search 60606 produces wrong city results

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

There seems to be an error on the careers 2.0 page.  When searching by just a zip code with a 20 mile radius, using 60606 returns data for Middlesex, NJ, despite being in Chicago.

Comment: `<snark type="bad">`Maybe there's a satanic filter which somehow thinks the 0's are NULLs?`</snark>`

Answer (score 4):

This should be fixed.  There is a great new tool on our side for fixing geo data cache issue quickly now!

Comment: [Another one, same issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230532/searching-by-zip-code-returns-results-for-a-different-location). :)