# Searching by zip code returns results for a different location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When doing a [job search, 02145](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=&location=02145), which is a zip code in Somerville, MA the site returns results for Zehdenick, Germany:

> [image]

Comment: Odd; Zehdenick's postal code is 16792. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_in_Germany#02000.E2.80.9302999))

Answer (score 1):

I changed it; this location is now set to 'Somerville, MA, United States' instead of 'Zehdenick, Germany'.

Comment: Cheers, you better mention you're a Careers dev in your profile and ask for a diamond here on MSE so that you can mark such questions [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @ShadowWizard done!

Comment: Shiny diamond is cool, but your MSE profile still lacks indication you're a dev. Sorry for nitpicking but MSE is all about nitpicking you know. :D